# How best to compress this folder so can be uncompressed withi Java with minimum working space

Tags: java, compression, gzip, tar

I have a folder containing files created on linux which i currently tar and compress with gzip(i.e tar.gz)

Then at a later stage the file is copied to another linux machine into one file system and extracted into another filesystem using Java.

My problem is the archive is 3GB compressed, 5GB uncompressed. The two file systems are 4GB and 6GB I copied the compressed archive to the 4GB fs but when I try to uncompress it to the 6GB it is copied to the 6GB fs as it is uncompressed, so the 6GB needs enough space for both the compressed and uncompressed formats which it does not.

I'm unclear why its creating this interim file, if I just do

```
cd destination folder
tar -zxvf source file
```

it works without running out of space, but I need to uncompress it using pure Java not the command line

Is there a better way to compress the folder as Im not constrained to any particular format as long as it can be uncompressed with Java code. I cannot modify/reconfigure the size of the two filesystems - it needs to work within these boundaries.

Comment: Begin uncompressing it as you transit the data? I say send it in 300mb chunks of compressed data and unzip it one at a time, you would stay well within the 1gb margin you have on either side

Comment: @ug_ more details please how do i break in into chunks that can be uncompressed independently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI:Just realized that in a tar.gz file the files are tarred and then then tar file is gzipped so when uncompressing the interim step of the unzipping to a tar is difficult to avoid. However if I **manually gzip each file and then tar** as follows:

```
cd foldertozip
gzip *
cd ..
tar -cvf foldertozip.tar folderzip
```

the size of foldertozip.tar is exactly the same as the original foldertozip.tar.gz but the interim step is not required.

Then later on I can:

- Copy foldertozip.tar to 4GB fs
- Untar foldertozip.tar to 6GB fs
- for each file in foldertozip
    Decompress each .gz

So the only additional temporary space we use on 6GB fs is what is required as decompress each gz file.

I've tested this out and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You got me curious about this one, and yea it wasn't to difficult. I used a TCP Server and Client just to completely separate out the Input/Output streams to ensure there were no shenanigans.

Essentially read in the raw ZIP data on the server and send it to the client. The client then interprets that data as a `ZipInputStream` and writes all the entries to an output folder. Turns out you dont even need to send in big chunks of data, only the buffers are really allocated. I profiled it sending over a 200mb zip file and the memory consumption barely got off the ground.

You do get a nice `SocketException` at the end but that is expected because I didnt add hardly any error handling other than the required. The client closes the connection and the server doesnt like that so it throws an error but all the data is done so who cares!

**I wrote This code for ZIP files because I wasnt paying attention but I figured I would post anway. You can adapt it to use a TAR input stream using some libraries online** But the code should give the general Jist.

```
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Object serverWait = new Object();
    startServer(serverWait);
    synchronized (serverWait) {
        // make sure our server is started and accepting clients, otherwise we run the risk of starting the client before the server is started
        serverWait.wait(2000);
    }
    startClient();
}

private static void startServer(final Object serverWait) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
            Socket socket = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5555);
                synchronized (serverWait) {
                    serverWait.notify();
                }
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Client accepted, sending data");
                // just send over the raw zip file and let the client sort through how to parse it
                is = new FileInputStream("f:\\so\\zip_transfer\\ZipFile.zip");

                int numRead = 0;
                byte [] buffer = new byte[2048];
                while((numRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    socket.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                safeClose(socket);
                safeClose(serverSocket);
                safeClose(is);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}


private static void startClient() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Socket socket = null;
            ZipInputStream is = null;
            try {
                socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5555);
                System.out.println("Client connected, retrieving data");

                // the data we are receiving is in zip format
                is = new ZipInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                extactZipInputStream(is, new File("f:\\so\\zip_transfer\\OutputDirectory"));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                safeClose(socket);
                safeClose(is);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public static void extactZipInputStream(ZipInputStream is, File outputFolder) throws ZipException, IOException  {

    ZipEntry entry = null;
    // Just keep going until we dont have any entries left.
    while((entry = is.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Entry: " + entry.getName());
        File file = new File(outputFolder, entry.getName());
        if(entry.isDirectory()) {
            // make all the path a direcotyr
            file.mkdirs();
        } else {
            // last one isnt a directory its our file, only make our parents
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

            // write the file to the system
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            int numRead = 0;
            byte [] buffer = new byte[2048];
            while((numRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
            }
            fos.close();
        }

        is.closeEntry();
    }
}

private static void safeClose(Closeable closable) {
    try {
        if(closable != null) {
            closable.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the effort but unfortunately your answer misses the key point that the files are tarred and then gzipped and hence have to be gzipped into a plain tar before untarring.  I now have a solution which I'll post in a minute